# Как реализовать поиск файлов по их названию и расширению,используя Lucene на C#?

Tags: c#, lucene

Вроде как индексировал и само содержимое файлов, и их имена, но что-то с поиском по второму никак не клеется... Пробовал многое, но результатов нет. Код немного обрезал и прокомментировал на "профанском" уровне

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Snowball;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable(); //объъявление таблицы
        public IndexWriter writer; //глобальный создатель индекса

        public Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directoryStandart; //директория стандартного индекса
        public Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directorySnowball; //директория стемминга индекса

        public string pathSourceFile; //директория, которую индексировать

        public Analyzer standart; //объявление имени стандартного анализатора
        public Analyzer snow; //объявление имени анализатора стемминга

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("№", typeof(int))); //добавление колоки с номером
            _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Путь к папке с индексами", typeof(string))); //добавление колоки с путем

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _dataTable; //присваем месту для таблицы саму таблицу

            standart = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);// морфологический анализатор
           //осуществляет приведение символов к нижнему регистру, удаление общих слов и знаков пунктуации
            snow = new SnowballAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "English"); //анализатор стемминга
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog(); //вызываем выбор директории
            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //если директория выбрана
            {
                _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dataTable.Rows.Count + 1, FBD.SelectedPath); //добавляем к таблице строку
                //с выбранным путем
                directoryStandart = FSDirectory.Open(FBD.SelectedPath); //присваиваем переменной путь к папке
                //для хранения стандартного индекса
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog(); //вызываем выбор директории
            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //если директория выбрана
            {
                _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dataTable.Rows.Count + 1, FBD.SelectedPath); //добавляем к таблице строку
                //с выбранным путем
                directorySnowball = FSDirectory.Open(FBD.SelectedPath);//присваиваем переменной путь к папке
                //для сохранения индекса Стемминга
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog(); //вызываем выбор директории
            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //если директория выбрана
            {
                pathSourceFile = FBD.SelectedPath;//присваиваем переменной путь к папке
                //для индексации
            }

            indexing(directoryStandart, standart);
            indexing(directorySnowball, snow);

            text1.Text = "Выполнено!";
        }

        private void indexing(Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory, Analyzer analyzer)
        {
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED); //создание индекса
            //В качестве параметров конструктору класса передаются следующие параметры: путь к директории индекса, 
            //объект морфологического анализатора, а также максимальная длина индексируемого поля
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathSourceFile); //объявление места 
            //откуда считаваются файлы для индексирование

            foreach (var file in files)//пока есть файлы
            {
                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);//выделеение текста
                string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);//выделение имени

                Document doc = new Document(); //Создание экземпляра класса

                doc.Add(new Field("name", name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)); //хранить  индексе имя файла и анализировать
                doc.Add(new Field("text", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

                writer.AddDocument(doc); //Добавление документв
            }
            writer.Optimize();
            writer.Dispose();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OutStandart.Text = "";
            OutStamming.Text = "";

            multiSeach();
        }

        public void multiSeach()
        {
                        // так как по одному слову, подаем сразу же это слово

                        char[] array = { ' ' };

                        List<string> queryStr = new List<string>();
                        queryStr.AddRange(Search.Text.Split(array, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                        if (queryStr.Count > 1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Введите одно слово");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IndexSearcher indexSearcher1 = new IndexSearcher(directoryStandart);
                            IndexSearcher indexSearcher2 = new IndexSearcher(directorySnowball);
                        //поиск файлов по индексу
                        Lucene.Net.Search.TopDocs results1 = indexSearcher1.Search(new TermQuery(
                                new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("text", queryStr[0])), null, Int32.MaxValue);
                        Lucene.Net.Search.TopDocs results2 = indexSearcher2.Search(new TermQuery(
                                new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("text", queryStr[0])), null, Int32.MaxValue);

                        //получаем список файлов
                        showResult(indexSearcher1, results1, OutStandart);
                        showResult(indexSearcher2, results2, OutStamming);
                    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем для поиска файлов по имени и расширению использовать такую библиотеку? Я бы понял, если бы вы вычитывали каждый файл из целевой директории, а потом искали бы по этому массиву данных. А так это совершенно бесполезное усложнение тривиальной задачи.

Comment: Дело в том, что требуется искать не только по точному имени, но и совпадения по лексемам, поэтому  и применял анализатор Snowball. И сказать честно, не знаю какие другие функции могут реализовать подобный функционал. Если подскажете, то буду рад

Comment: Приведите примеры такого поиска. Например есть файлы: `echo1.txt`, `EchoR.txt`, `Foo.txt`, `BAr.log`, `BarrFoo.log`. Какие тут будут лексемы для поиска?

Comment: Возможно это поможет?: `foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(PathToOrders).Where(p=>p.Contains("Order") && p.Contains(".txt"));`

Comment: В данном случае не знаю, как будет работать, но если названия будут: Reader.txt, Read.txt, Tools.txt и т.д. , то на запрос "Read" будут найдены два первых файла. На сколько я знаю Snowball выделяет лексему(основу слова) и преверяет по словарю, если не нашел, то слово отвергает, т.е. поиск по нему ничего не находит

Comment: @SashaGri я тебя не понял. Если у тебя разные варианты названий  можно сделать такой запрос - `Where(p=>p.Contains("Read") || Where(p=>p.Contains("Tools")` или вынести наименования в список.

Comment: @Сергей Татевосян, я вас понял, спасибо. Я попробую это реализовать. Просто пока нет возможности и плюс надо разобраться , а то я можно сказать новичок в этой области(считая и сам язык)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вопрос был поставлен при условии, что должен использоваться Lucene. Ответы и комментарии, которые давались использовали другие библиотеки и функции, которые не соответствуют требованиям для реализации проекта в дальнейшей перспективе. Если говорить проще, ответы давались не совсем по теме.
Теперь к решению. Код рабочий, но в этой строке: 
`string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);`
Происходило извлечение имени файла вместе с расширением (text.txt). Я думал, что извлекается просто имя (text) и в поиске забивал не то, что надо. Поэтому и думал, что код не рабочий. 
Следовательно для решения вопроса потребовалось применить функции извлечения только имени и только расширения. После этого для каждого из наборов построить индекс и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Чем вам стандартные методы Net Framework не подходят?
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", @"*.exe").ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));